# Vue :to from a properties

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

I create my list of views link from a array in my data but it`s possible to bind the :to property to a item in my object? something link this

```
<v-list-tile v-else @click="" :to="{name: '{{item.componentName}}'}" :key="item.text">
            <v-list-tile-action>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-action>
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-list-tile-title>
                {{ item.text }}
              </v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever in v-bind should be a valid Javascript expression

in this case, it should just be a valid Javascript Object

`:to="{name: item.componentName}"`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're attempting variable interpolation (the `{{item.componentName}}` part) within a v-bind expression. This isn't supported.

Instead, you can use any valid JavaScript expression and it will automatically detect component-level data scoping (even in a `v-for` loop!). For instance, your desired expression should be this:

```
:to="{name: item.componentName}"
```

As noted with `v-for`, the following toy example would also be valid:

```
<div v-for="(item, item_index) in itemsArray">
    <my-component :myProp="{name: item.componentName, position: item_index}"></my-component>
</div>
```

Interpolation is only necessary if you're attempting to render some value outside of a v-binding, e.g. displaying some text:

```
<div>{{item.componentName}}</div>
```